# Any file system debugger similar to `fsdb` in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, filesystems

I'm now studying Linux file system and curious about how to read an i-node with a i-node # get from `ls -i`? Seems `fsdb` in Unix is such a tool but didn't find its correspondent in Linux.

Thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`debugfs`** from *e2fsprogs* works on ext2/ext3/ext4 filesystems. Use its *`stat`* command; the inode number must  be given in `< >`.

```
# debugfs /dev/sdz1
debugfs:  stat <42>
```

For JFS, *`inode`* in **`jfs_debugfs`** (*jfsutils*):

```
# jfs_debugfs /dev/sdz1
> inode 42
```

For XFS, use **`xfs_db`** (*xfsprogs*):

```
# xfs_db /dev/sdz1
xfs_db> inode 42
xfs_db> print
```

For NTFS, use **`ntfsinfo`** (*ntfsprogs*):

```
# ntfsinfo -i 42 /dev/sdz1
```